# How to use sweetalert when delete row in table

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I want to use sweetalert when delete data in table before it linking  my controller. But it only call my controller and don't show any alert.

```
<a href="Table/Delete/<?php echo ($u->ID) ?>">
     <button id="a" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete </button>
</a>
```

js

```
<script>
   $('#a').on('click',function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
         swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
         })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
             swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
             icon: "success",
          });
          } else {
            swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
          });
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using sweetalert2 ? or any other library?

Comment: [link](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

Answer (score 0):

don't use `<a href="...">` link

HTML should be like ..

```
<div>
  <button id="a"></button>
</div>
```

js should be like following

```
<script>
   $('#a').on('click',function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
         swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
         })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
             # delete row
             # show swal and redirect to your link
          } else {
            swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
          });
   })
</script>
```

Comment: I try use this but it same <a href="Table/Delete/<?php echo ($u->ID) ?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>

Comment: Don’t use ‘<a href>’

Comment: i want to delete row